# find email and userID in cookie with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, cookies

I am storing a cookie on one page, with inputs in a form with this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function WriteCookie()
{
   emailValue = escape(document.form.01_email.value) + ";";
   userIDValue = escape(document.form.01_userID.value) + ";";

   document.cookie="email=" + emailValue;
   document.cookie="userID=" + userIDValue;
}
</script>

<form name="form">
 <input type="email" class="form-textbox validate[required, Email]" id="input_10" name="01_email" size="26" value="email@email.com" />
 <input type="hidden" id="simple_spc" name="01_userId" value="1234" />
</form>
```

I get redirect to another page once a user submits the form, and I retrieve the cookie with this code but i need to have it find the email and userID in the cookie and insert it in the value of the inputs on this new page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ReadCookie()
    {
       var allcookies = document.cookie;
       alert("All Cookies : " + allcookies );

       // Get all the cookies pairs in an array
       cookiearray  = allcookies.split(';');

       // Now take key value pair out of this array
       for(var i=0; i<cookiearray.length; i++){
          name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];
          value = cookiearray[i].split('=')[2];
          alert("Email is : " + name + " and UserID is : " + value);
       }
    }
    </script>


    <form name="form">
     <input type="email" class="form-textbox" id="input_10" name="02_email" size="26" value="" />
     <input type="hidden" id="simple_spc" name="02_userId" value="" />
    </form>
```

I know a user will most likely have multiple cookies, so finding only the email and userID i'm having trouble with.

Comment: Are you using any Javascript library? jQuery, YUI, &c.?

Comment: no, just regular javascript, no libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to read your cookies.

```
function ReadCookie(){
    var key, value, i;
    var cookieArray  = document.cookie.split(';');

    for (i = 0; i < cookieArray.length; i++){
        key = cookieArray[i].substr(0, cookieArray[i].indexOf("="));
        value = cookieArray[i].substr(cookieArray[i].indexOf("=")+1);

        if (key == 'email'){
            alert('Email is ' + value);
        }

        if (key == 'userID'){
            alert('userID is ' + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am only getting the userID using this, the email doesn't portion doesn't seem to work?

Comment: `key = key.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");` add this line after `value = cookieArray[i].substr(cookieArray[i].indexOf("=")+1);`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
// Now take key value pair out of this array
for(var i=0; i<cookiearray.length; i++){
    name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];
    value = cookiearray[i].split('=')[2];
    if (name == "email") 
      alert("Email is : " + value);
    if (name == "userID") 
      alert("UserID is : " + value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't take credit for this answer, but one can't do better than PPK at quirksmode.org for elegance in a solution with the "why it works" baked in.

Here's the code:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date(), 
        expires = "";
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
  } else {
    document.cookie = name+"=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=", 
      ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
      c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) {
      return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
   createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Here's [PPK on Cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

HTH

Comment: If you want an richer API to cookies, consider YUI Cookie Utility or the jQuery Cookie Plugin. The [YUI Cookie Utility](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/cookie/) is very nice (with a small dependency on the YAHOO object).